# how to retrieve record from multiple table in a single view using entity framework databse first approach in mvc?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show records of multiple table in a single view using entity framework database first approach.

this is my controller class:

```
       public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var query = (from c in db.tblBlogs
                     join d in db.tblBlogComments on c.id equals d.BlogId
                     join e in
                   db.tblBlogLikes on c.id equals e.BlogId
                     join f in db.tblBlogMedias on c.id equals f.BlogId
                     where c.id == d.BlogId || c.id == e.BlogId || c.id == 
                 f.BlogId
                     select c).OrderByDescending(d => 
               d.id).ToList().Take(6);

            return View(query);
        }
```

How can i show these records from multiple table in single view ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what's your question here.. is there any issue in your query

Comment: Is there any relation between these tables? How many fields from which table will show in this view. Can you please clear?

Comment: The issue is im not able the bind the data of all tables in Index.cshtml file.

Comment: @foreach(var item in Model)
{ <h1>@item.BlogPicture</h1>
<h2>@item.Title</>
<h2>@item.Description</h2>
}

here all three items are from different tables. I want to bind those data from different tables  here.